# Burst in or into laughter?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, phrases, prepositions

Which of the following phrases is correct grammatically?

> - burst **in** laughter
> - burst **into** laughter

Or are they both correct (this is my guess)?

I'd think that to "burst in laughter" could translate to something like "burst in a state of laughter." Is this correct?

Comment: The fixed phrase is _burst **into** laughter_. _In_ is not used.

Comment: Related: _[Is “burst oneself laughing” a valid expression?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/66689/5822)_

Comment: Although one might hear _[bursting out in laughter](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22bursting+out+in+laughter%22)_

Comment: @J.R.: That's exactly it, and can't "out" be remove from that sentence while maintaining proper grammar?

Comment: If the joke is funny enough, I might _burst out in laughter_, or I might _burst into laughter_, but I won't _burst in laughter_.  The word "in" is just not used that way.

Answer (score 7):

I've never heard or read "burst in laughter" in 65+ years of reading and speaking, so "I'd have to say that "burst into laughter" is the correct idiom. "Burst in a state of laughter" doesn't mean the same thing as "burst into laughter". The latter phrase means that someone suddenly started laughing rather loudly (bombs burst and make big noises), while "Burst in a state of laughter" means that someone or something (a robot?) broke (burst or exploded like a balloon) while laughing. Idioms often cannot be understood simply by looking at the words they contain.

Comment: "He burst in laughter" ... meaning: He laughed so hard that he burst.  Hopefully just some buttons came loose, and not a more serious form of bursting...

Answer (score 2):

To express sudden utterance or expression usual collocation is **burst into**

```
He burst into tears.
```

In some situations **in** might be possible to imply sudden movement or action. Compare:

```
He burst in without knocking.
he burst into the room.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "to burst out laughing" is more widely used.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Nels_on. 
We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Can you substantiate your answer in some way? Otherwise, it's just your opinion, which is of no more value to Purag than my opinion :-)

Answer (score -2):

A common expression is "to burst out laughing". But there are variants, of course.

Comment: While that is true, I don't see how this answers the question.